# CakePHP AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

So i have the following relation:

**User:**

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * User Model
 *
 * @property Roles $Roles
 */
class User extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));
    public $belongsTo = array('Role');

    public function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($this->data['User']['role_id'])) {
            $roleId = $this->data['User']['role_id'];
        } else {
            $roleId = $this->field('role_id');
        }
        if (!$roleId) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array('Role' => array('id' => $roleId));
        }
    }
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'username';


    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        return true;
    }

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
}
```

**Role:**

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Role extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));
    public function parentNode() {
        return null;
    }

    public $displayField = 'name';

}
```

I have setup the Aro and aco tables in my database. Now when ever i try to add a user i get the following error message:

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => Role [Aro0.foreign_key] => 1 ) "
```

I feel like ive tried everything.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

My save logic (Add action):

```
        public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $roles = $this->User->Role->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('roles'));
}
```

**Error message and stacktrace:**

```
    2013-09-13 14:28:56 Error: [CakeException] AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array
(
    [Aro0.model] => Role
    [Aro0.foreign_key] => 1
)
"
Request URL: /udlejnings-priser/cake/users/add
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/AclBehavior.php(92): AclNode->node(Array)
#1 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/AclBehavior.php(110): AclBehavior->node(Object(User), Array, 'Aro')
#2 [internal function]: AclBehavior->afterSave(Object(User), true, Array)
#3 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php(132): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 [internal function]: ObjectCollection->trigger(Object(CakeEvent))
#5 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php(248): call_user_func(Array, Object(CakeEvent))
#6 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1789): CakeEventManager->dispatch(Object(CakeEvent))
#7 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2270): Model->save(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2073): Model->saveAssociated(Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/app/Controller/UsersController.php(82): Model->saveAll(Array)
#10 [internal function]: UsersController->add()
#11 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(490): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(UsersController), Array)
#12 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(187): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#13 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#14 /var/www/udlejnings-priser/cake/app/webroot/index.php(110): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#15 {main}
```

**My Post request**

```
    Data = {array}[1]
  User = {array}[3]
       username = test2
       password = test
       role_id = 1
```

**Cake version 2.4.0**

Comment: what is the query being executed ? also, paste your save logic

Comment: @AyoAkinyemi where can i see the query being executed?

Comment: after this call:   if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {, you can get the query by calling $this->User->getDataSoure()->getLog()

Comment: have you stored data in your Roles table ?

Comment: @AyoAkinyemi i can't get that log because it throws an error at saveAll Also yes i have three different roles: Admin, Udlejer and Lejer

Comment: can you paste your post data? what version of cakePHP are you on ?

Comment: @AyoAkinyemi updated my original post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37335/discussion-between-marc-and-ayo-akinyemi)

Comment: So what is the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the error because lft and rght columns were null. Missed it in
[cakephp Automated tool for creating ACOs manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html).
Solved it by running console script:

```
cake AclExtras.AclExtras recover aro
```